# Spilt coffee on Keyboard, washed/dryed but 2 keys still not working, any cure?

Tags: keyboard, hardware

I spilt coffee on an apple external wired keyboard. Taking the advice of other threads on this matter I washed it thoroughly and dried it, twice. However 2 of the keys are still non functional. Does this mean it is permanently busted? Or can I still fix it somehow? Or can it economically be fixed by an apple support shop or similar??

Answer (score 1):

What model is it? Take off the back to get to the logic board and membrane and clean each with isopropyl alcohol, I repair Apple stuff and as long as the board and membrane are dry before you power them, the alcohol shouldn't hurt anything. If the key's still aren't working, don't throw the keyboard away, sell it for parts on eBay. You might make a little bit of money and someone might be happy to buy it just for keys and the case.

Comment: This is the one i have http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB110LL/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-english-usa

Comment: I thought you said it was wired? There are ways of cleaning a WIRELESS keyboard, but I've heard that they never look the same again. Try cleaning between the keys with isopropyl alcohol.

Comment: It is wired, and so is the product i linked. I dont see a way to get lower than just removing the key caps, I have removed those and cleaned with hot water, ill try alcohol next.